# Subsite provisioning from WSP - JSLinks

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, jslink

We are provisioning the subsites from a saved template (WSP). Everything works properly apart from the JSLinks in list forms, these are not being loaded.

What we have noticed is that the ~sitecollection tokens are being replaced automatically with the server relative URL of the Site Collection.

Basically in template we have something like this:

```
~sitecollection/Style Library/JS/fileName.js
```

After provisioning it looks like this:

```
/SiteCollectionRoot/Style Library/JS/fileName.js
```

Edit:
I know what the purpose of "~sitecollection" token is. However, when automatically replaced by SharePoint while provisioning the template it breaks the JSLinks. It should stay in form of the tokens in order for the JSLinks to work.

Comment: That is exactly what the `~sitecollection` token is supposed to do, at execution time it is supposed to translate into the site collection's URL. If you need it to reference the subsite instead, then you should use the `~site` token.

Comment: The relative URLs don't work as JSLinks there. When we replace the "/SiteCollectionRoot/Style Library/" with "~sitecollection/Style Library/" the things are starting to work back again.